# Python: adding sets in a set during a 'For loop' and do the 'For loop' only for the added sets

Tags: python, for-loop, iteration, nested-for-loop

I have one initial SET containing sets within it. And I want to do a 'For loop' for each set and if conditions are met after doing some function, create a new sets and add them to the original SET. E.g.

```
Org_Set = {frozenset({1}), frozenset({2}), frozenset({3}), frozenset({4})}

for s in Org_Set:    
     C = set(s)
     if 'conditions are met':
         D = set('some elements')
         Org_Set.add(frozenset(D))
```

In each iteration, the newly added sets (in my specific case) have one more length (number of elements) than the old sets. E.g. the result after one iteration would be:

```
Org_Set = {frozenset({1}), frozenset({2}), frozenset({3}), frozenset({4}), frozenset({1,4}), frozenset({2,3})}
```

See that the Org_Set now contains both the old and newly added sets, but I want to do the 'For Loop' only for the newly added sets, just to reduce the amount of run time (for large data).

Basically, I have tried this: first I have created a copy of the original variable, then create a set that would contain the diffrence of the original set and the copy set, and then do the 'For Loop' for this set, described as follows:

```
Org_Set = {frozenset({1}), frozenset({2}), frozenset({3}), frozenset({4})}
Copied_Org_set = Org_Set.copy()
Difference_set= Org_Set.diffrence(Copied_Org_set)
for s in Difference_set:
      C = set(s)
      if 'conditions are met':
           D = set('some elements')
           Org_Set.add(frozenset(D))
```

But, it didnt work. I am now looking for your kind suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

In Python, sets do not have a specified iteration order; adding new elements to the set during an iteration has unspecified results (and usually they are not very pleasant).

Since Python 3.7, dictionaries do have a specified iteration order (the order in which the keys were inserted into the dictionary. However, it is still not permitted to modify a dictionary during iteration over a view of that dictionary (and it is only possible to iterate over views).

So for now you have to maintain your own iterable, as well as the set:

```py
Org_Set = {frozenset({1}), frozenset({2}), frozenset({3}), frozenset({4})}
Org_Values = list(Org_Set)
for fs in Org_Values:
    # ...
    if some_condition:
        d = frozenset(some_values)
        if d not in Org_Set:
            Org_Set.add(d)
            Org_Values.append(d)
```

You could wrap that all into a custom OrderedSet object, perhaps derived from [`collections.abc.MutableSet`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html), which would make for a more convenient (and complete) interface, but that might be overkill for a simple application.

Comment: Dear rici thank you. I didnt know that sets do not have a specified iteration order. Its a great lesson. I applied your suggestion and got the correct output. But, how could I know that the loop was done also for the newly added elements? (How can I track the iteration process?)

Second thing is, since the newly added elements (sets) in each iteration have a length which is one more than the old (in previous iteration), is there a way to use this logic: like to consider only those sets where len(new_elements) > len(old_elements)?

The collections.abc.MutableSet looks advanced for me.

Comment: @user20083894: I'm not sure what you mean by "track the iteration progress". The iteration will definitely iterate over each element exactly once in insertion order, so you will see them in the order you add them to the set. You just have to make sure that you always follow the logic for adding a new element, which is the last three lines. (I'd put those into a function so that you don't accidentally do it wrong somewhere.) As for collections.abc, it is advanced Python, but it's not so hard. You should constantly challenge yourself to better understand your tools. But it's just a suggestion.